# how to send 'boolean' type data from HTML form to the database

Tags: html, mysql, forms, laravel, boolean

> how to **send** '**bit**' type data from HTML form to the database.

can we  convert it into boolean or something like that. I have tried using `type='number'` and it didn't work. I get this error:

```
 ... SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'active' at row 1 (SQL: insert into pg_vendor ...
```

here column active is of datatype `bit` which is either 0 or 1.

I've also used boolean, text, number type and it didn't work.

*I'm using Laravel*
Thanks

Comment: I think I see what you mean, can you intercept the data and translate it into a more acceptable value for your db? Checkbox should be fine for that. And only saving it if it's a 1, just leave it empty if it's none. Make sure columns is nullable.

Comment: hey there thank you,But i can't change the values of the Db. It breaks the whole work flow of the previously developed system. And checkbox sends data as a string not as a bit type. I want it to be sent as a bit type data. :)

Comment: have you tried intercepting it with js using `$('#the_form').submit(function(){/*grab value and convert here*/});`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with checkbox or radio:

```
$value = $request->input('bit') ? 1 : 0;

$bit = new Bit;
$bit->bit = $value;
$bit->save();
```

Comment: sorry, i'm new to laravel. Is there any chance of changing the datatype before POSTing in HTML? Check box and Radio does not work. Thanks